# Why does New-ELBLoadBalancer fail with a WebException?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-powershell

I'm trying to create an ELB using powershell using the script below, but it's failing with **"New-ELBLoadBalancer : A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown."** I'm not sure where to start, any hints?

```
$HTTPListener = New-Object -TypeName ‘Amazon.ElasticLoadBalancing.Model.Listener’
$HTTPListener.Protocol = ‘http’
$HTTPListener.InstancePort = 80
$HTTPListener.LoadBalancerPort = 80

New-ELBLoadBalancer -LoadBalancerName 'my-elb' -Listener $HTTPListener -Scheme 'internet-facing' -SecurityGroup 'sg-74d60410' -Subnet 'subnet-efc9b8d5' -AccessKey x -SecretKey x -Region us-west1
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the region name had a typo should have been us-west-1

Answer (score 0):

Some more background on the error:

> A WebException with status NameResolutionFailure was thrown.

When you specify a region for a given AWS cmdlet, you're calling out to a specific service for that region.  So when you call `New-ELBLoadBalancer` in `us-west-1`, behind-the-scenes an API call is being made to `elasticloadbalancing.us-west-1.amazonaws.com`. So this WebException is common to the AWS cmdlets, and any AWS cmdlet made with a malformed region will throw this.

Documentation:

- [AWS Documentation - Regions and Endpoints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html)